# HTML Makeshift Template System

Tags: php, html

On my website i've got a number of folders named news / blog / products etc... all of these sections are virtually the same setup apart from small internal styling changes in the head, instead of copying and pasting the same file n-amount of times i'd rather have a template, and I started doing it like this:

- Each section has a 'base' .php file called (news.php / blog.php / products.php etc...)
- Each page has 2 includes:

  ```
  <?php
       include "../article_template/part1.html";
  ?>

  // Each pages internal styling goes here

  <?php
      include "../article_template/part2.html";
  ?>
  ```

Part 1.html:

```
<?php
    require_once "directory/functions.php";
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://example.org/folder/style1.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://example.org/folder/style2.css">

<style type="text/css">
```

Part 2.html:

```
</style>

<title> <?php get_title(explode('/', $_GET['$url'])); ?></title>

</head><body>
<?php 
    include "../topborder.html";
    include "../banner.php";
    include "../navbar.html";
?>
<div id="container">
<div id = "article_container">
    <?php
        $uri = explode('/', $_GET['$url']);
        get_article($uri[0]);
    ?>
</div>
<?php include "../folder/sidepanel.html"; ?>
</div></body></html>
```

In between parts 1 and 2 I can just slot in the internal styling for the page. While this is working fine, it seems a little hacky - am i going to run into many performance or any other issues with a setup like this? - While this setup is easier for me as I only have to change 1 file to effect all areas I'm a little worried about the performance. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Consider using DRY principle ( Don't Repeat Yourself ), instead of using `include "../navbar.html"` replace it with a function like `get_navbar()` or may be a function with multiple templates like `get_view('navbar')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repeating yourself costs more time up front, and potentially a lot more down the road if you have to go back and make the same change in multiple places. DRY ( Don't Repeat Yourself ) reduces duplication and the maintenance problems coming with it.

In your example you're including different HTML files, we can make a function that includes any of your HTML templates. Benefits: shorter code, you don't need to remember the path of every file, if you need to change an HTML file you only do this once.

```
<?php

    // Add this to functions

    function get_template($template = '') {

        $path = '/absolute/path'; // Absolute path to your project

        $templates = array(
            'topBorder' => '/views/topborder.html',
            'banner' => '/views/banner.html',
            'navBar' => '/views/navBar.html',
            'sidePanel' => '/views/sidepanel.html'
        );

        if(isset($templates[$template])) {
            $templateFile = $path . $templates[$template];
            if(file_exists($templateFile))
                include($templateFile);
        }

    }

    // Instead of including some static HTML
    // We only call the function with the corresponding template

    get_template('navBorder');
    get_template('banner');
    get_template('navBar');
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the same layout technique as a WordPress page uses. You shall be fine. If you need proof download a free WordPress theme and take a look at it.

Comment: Oo i've never used wordpress, good to know someone else is doing it, but isn't there an issues that instead of downloading 1 php file with everything in - its download the base file, then the two parts? it's like 3x as much work?

Comment: Yes, but you are downloading from the same server, and maintainability will pay off. Sure it would be faster in one file, but much less maintainable.

Comment: This be true, just checked out a wordpress theme, guess i'll use this system :p

Answer (score 0):

> I'm a little worried about the performance. Is there a better way to
>   do this?

Why? The PHP tags coming before HTML means 100% of nothing.  The PHP will be acted on as PHP & the second the HTML `<!DOCTYPE html>` comes along, it gets spit directly through the web server as HTML.